# How to get the minimal value for all rows before x days in the past in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Let's say that I have the following table `tbl` with all rows having the same `id` to simplify things

```
timestamp   amount
------------------
01-01-2021  10      
02-01-2021  15      
03-01-2021  11      
02-02-2021  20      
01-04-2021  9
```

I want as a new column `prev_min` the minimal amount for all orders which are **at least x days** in the past. This would result in:

```
timestamp   amount   prev_min
--------------------------------
01-01-2021  10       NULL
02-01-2021  15       NULL
03-01-2021  11       NULL
02-02-2021  20       10           -- since 11 & 15 are not > 30 days in the past
01-04-2021  9        11           -- since 11 is > 30 days in the past
```

My approach is something like that

```sql
SELECT 
    MIN(CASE WHEN timestamp < timestamp - INTERVAL '30 DAYS' 
        THEN amount 
        ELSE 0 END) 
    OVER (
        PARTITION BY id
        ORDER BY timestamp ASC
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 30 PRECEDING
    ) AS prev_min
FROM tbl
```

I know that the `CASE WHEN ...` is wrong. And I also know that the `30 PRECEDING` is starting from 30 rows before the current row and thus is also wrong. And I don't want e.g. 30 *rows* in the past but rather 30 *days* in the past. I can't use `RANGE` however.
So is there a way to do that without using `RANGE`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to have rows for every date so you can use the frame clause of the window function the way you want.  I used a recursive CTE to generate all the dates of 2021 but you can expand this as you need.

Test case:

Setup:

```
create table t (dt date, amount int);
  
insert into t values  
('01-01-2021', 10),     
('01-02-2021', 15),    
('01-03-2021', 11),    
('02-02-2021', 8),    
('04-01-2021', 9);
```

Query:

```
with recursive dates(d) as
( select '2021-01-01'::date as d
    union all
    select (d + 1)::date as d
    from dates d
    where d.d <= '2021-12-31'::date
    )
select dt, amount, prev_min
from (
  select dt, sum(amount) as amount, max(orig) as orig,
  min(sum(amount)) over (
        ORDER BY dt ASC
        ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 30 PRECEDING) as prev_min
  from (
    select dt, amount, 1 as orig from t 
    union all
    select d as dt, null as amount, 0 as orig from dates
  ) as a
  group by dt
) b
where orig = 1
order by dt
;
```

Adding in your id partition and any other specifics should be straight forward from here.

Comment: You mean I need to have rows for every date _per_ id. I have that. In general I have rows for every date yes. And per date a lot of rows also. But isn't `30 PRECEDING` trying to go 30 rows in the past and not 30 days? So when some `id` has a row at time t and one row at t-10days and one at t-32 days isnt it then not getting the row at t-32 days. I am still missing something in my understanding here, sorry.

Comment: Since the query is grouped by dt there is only one row per date in this example but when we add id back in you will need a row per date per id.  Remember that GROUP BY runs before window functions and this is making sure there is only one row per dt in this example.  Now if you want to do this per id you will need to have every date for every id in the result of subquery 'a', group by id and dt, and partition by id in the window function.  To get subquery 'a' to have what you want a cross joining will be needed and this will be most efficient if "dates" is a dist-all table.